# Consulta MySQL ¿cómo filtrar 2 condiciones?

Tags: mysql

Necesito una sentencia para resolver el siguiente problema:

Escriba una sentencia que devuelva todos los conductores en España mayores de 25 años con un coche rojo.

Columnas en la tabla uno referentes al problema:
id (referencia de driver_id)
full_name
age

Columnas de la tabla dos referentes al problema:
driver_id
color

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT full_name
FROM spain_drivers
WHERE age >= 25
IN(SELECT color FROM spain_cars WHERE color = 'RED')
```

El resultado ha sido la devolución de todos los nombres independientemente de lo que requiero.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma practica es hacer un inner join entre ambas tablas, creo entender que tienen el campo llamado driver_id en comun, aqui te dejo como creo que puede funcionar

```
select full_name from tabla1 t1
inner join tabla2 t2 on t1.driver_id=t2.driver_id
where age>25 and color='red'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo cierto es que funcionó pero quité "=" para que los resultados sean mayores de 25 únicamente.

Comment: Lo agregue sin querer, donde trabajo siempre piden consultas para rangos de dia y siempre lo agrego, disculpa
PD: lo edite de todas formas

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy resolviendo pruebas técnicas para un empleo y MySQL se me complica un poco todavía, tengo que meterle mucha caña :D

Comment: En efecto, con practica y bastantes ganas se puede, suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `INNER JOIN` el cuál se utiliza para mostrar los datos coincidentes en ambas tablas de acuerdo a los parámetros que pases en la cláusula `WHERE`.

*El ejercicio menciona que solo son los **mayores de 25**, por esa razón en el ejemplo no utilizo `>=`*

```
SELECT A.full_name, A.age, B.color
FROM spain_drivers A
INNER JOIN spain_cars B ON A.driver_id = B.driver_id
WHERE A.age > 25
AND B.color = 'RED'
```

Más información sobre `INNER JOIN` [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)